# Android in-app billing Purchase dialog not showing after startPurchaseFlow() is called

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Hello guys and good saturday everyone,

For the first time i'm implementing an in-app billing service in my app, the aim is  to make a "Buy pro and remove ads" button inside app menu, quite simple actually.

Following some guides i made a BillingManager.java:

```
public class BillingManager implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
private static final String TAG = "BillingManager";

private final BillingClient mBillingClient;
private final Activity mActivity;

public BillingManager(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mActivity).setListener(this).build();
    mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponse) {
            if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: " + billingResponse);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: " + billingResponse);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, List<Purchase> purchases) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated() response: " + responseCode);
}

public void startPurchaseFlow(String skuId, String billingType) {
    BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setType(billingType).setSku(skuId).build();
    mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(mActivity, billingFlowParams);
    Log.i(TAG, "Received command");
}}
```

and then i'm calling it inside MainActivity in the menu:

```
 if (id == R.id.action_pro) {
        BillingManager mbilling = new BillingManager(MainActivity.this);
        mbilling.startPurchaseFlow("mysku", BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        return true;
    }
```

But when i press the button corresponding to "action_pro" Nothing happens.

All the logs shows everything is fine, onBillingSetupFinished() response is always 0 and onPurchaseUpdated() response is alwasy -1.

There aren't any crashes or error, just nothing happens...

What can i do?

Any answer is as always highly appreciated!

Edit: i put a logger for debug and i se that if put `int response = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(mActivity, builder.build());
        Log.i(TAG, "Response code: "+ response);`

i get the error: `I/BillingManager: Response code: -1`

So actually `mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(mActivity, builder.build());` throws -1 as result... Any ideas?